# How do you organize your geodata?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, feature-dataset

A geodatabase doesn't provide much flexibility in organizing your data hierarchically. All feature sets live either at the top level of the database, or one level down in feature datasets. A feature dataset can't, in turn, contain another dataset. I'm interested in hearing how others organize their data, especially in environments where they must use a geodatabase and are stuck with these limitations.

Comment: Enterprise Geodatabase (ArcSDE) support Versioning http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002nt000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical organization methods that I've seen are by prefixing.  In an enterprise geodatabase, this can be done with an owner/schema name (e.g. `UTIL.WMETER` or by prefixing the featureclass/table name itself with a prefix string, then underscore, then name `UTIL_WMETER`).  Prefixing the featureclass/table name also works in personal/file geodatabases.

Because of editing overhead for feature datasets, they aren't usually used as a primary  organizational mechanism.